# React Redux form - preload value in modal and pass changed values to parent

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I am implementing a redux form based modal that is called inside a parent component. Parent component passes a variable (myVariable) via props to the child modal, when the modal is opened. This value is PRELOADED in the input field inside the modal.

when a user changes value in the input filed, and submits the modal, modal closes and the value gets passed to the parent component and updates the parent component value, that was originally passed to the modal.

PARENT COMPONENT

```
//import statements

export class ParentComponent extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      isOpenModal: false
    }

    this.submitAction = this.submitAction.bind(this)
  }

  submitAction = (values) => {
    console.log('submit action ', values)
  }

  render () {
    const {isOpenModal} = this.state
    const { myVariable } = this.props

    return (
      <div>
        { myVariable }

        <MyModal
          isOpenModal={isOpenModal}
          onSave={this.handleSave}
          myVariable={myVariable}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const formName = 'setMyForm'
const selector = formValueSelector(formName)

export const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
      //TODO
  }
}

const SetMyForm = connect(mapStateToProps)(ParentComponent)

export default reduxForm({
  form: formName,
  onSubmitFail: focusOnField(formName)
})(ParentComponent)
```

CHILD MODAL COMPONENT

```
//import statements - react, redux, redux form

let initialValues = {}
export class MyModal extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    const {isOpenModal} = this.props
    this.state = {
      isOpenModal
    }

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  handleSubmit (values) {
    const { myVariable } = values
  }

  render () {
    const { isOpenModal, myVariable } = this.props
    initialValues.myVariable = myVariable

    return (
      <CustomModal 
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleSubmit)}>
            <div>
            <Field
                  name='myVariable'
                  label='TEST'
                  type='text'
                  component={renderInputField}
                  />
            </div>
            <div>
              <div>
                <button type='submit' value='Save' />
              </div>
            </div>

        </form>
      </CustomModal>
    )
  }
}

MyModal.propTypes = {
  isOpenModal: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
}

const formName = 'modalForm'
const selector = formValueSelector(formName)

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
     initialValues: {
       myVariable: selector(state, 'myVariable'),
     }
  }
}

const MyModalComp = connect(mapStateToProps)(MyModal)

export default reduxForm({
  form: formName,
  initialValues: initialValues,
  onSubmitFail: focusOnField(formName)

})(MyModalComp)
```

What is missing in this code?

Comment: Can you please add the `this.handleSave` of the PARENT component.

Comment: Is there some error?? what is failing, setting the initial value or passing values back to parent

Comment: the value when saved , doesn't get changed in the parent

Comment: changed value is  even available in the console log of the submit action in the parent.

console.log('submit action ', values)

but how that needs to be passed to { myVariable } to reflect what was changed inside the modal is my issue.